# Custom Action_Bar with textview android

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom action bar as shown in the image below:

[image]

I also have list view. In each row of the list, it contains  plus and minus images button. I want to show when I press plus button, the action bar textView should be show  1,  and if i press plus button again this should increase by one and show 2.

Please check my code below and let me know how to solve this issue.

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {
    String title;
    ListView listView;
    ImageView imageView,imageView1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        ActionBar.LayoutParams lp = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.actionbarlayout, null); // layout which contains your button.
        actionBar.setCustomView(customNav, lp);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");

        listView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.plus);
        imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.minus);
    }

    public void plusClick(View v)
    {
        if (listView.getPositionForView(v)==0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "this is Plus1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if (listView.getPositionForView(v)==1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "this is Plus2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Below is my class adapter

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemData> {

protected ListView mListView;

private final List<ItemData> items;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ItemData> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items != null ? items.size() : 0;
}

@Override
public ItemData getItem(int position) {


    return super.getItem(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;






    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        int layout = R.layout.item_layout;
        v = inflater.inflate(layout, null);

        holder.tt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.team);
        holder.tt12 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        holder.img1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.plus);
        holder.img2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.minus);
        v.setTag(holder);



    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }


    if (position %2==0){

        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.color1);

    }
    else {
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.color2);
    }


    ItemData p = items.get(position); //getItem(position);

    holder.tt1.setText(p.getTitle());
    holder.tt12.setText(p.getDetails());
    holder.img.setImageDrawable(p.getImage());
    holder.img1.setImageDrawable(p.getImageplus());
    holder.img2.setImageDrawable(p.getImageminus());

    Log.i("fff", "getView: image = " + p.getImage());

    //load image directly


    return v;
}




static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tt1, tt12;
    ImageView img,img1,img2;

}
```

}

Comment: Please re-upload your image. The current link is incorrect.

Comment: can you see the image now ??

Comment: Yup, great. `.png` was missing from the previous URL. Cheers.

Comment: Your problem is ?

Comment: When i press plus button from list view then in action bar instead of textview it should show 1 and if i press plus button again its should increase by one

Comment: where are your class adapter  for listView?

Comment: I added the adapter thanks

Comment: @BarryO'Reilly You can get a reference to your action bar like any other view for example: TextView yourTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextView); . after that in your adapter you should catch clicks on the plus button and update the activity layout accordingly. it could be done by using interface or passing the activity instance to the adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try update your code with this

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {
    String title;
    ListView listView;
    ListViewAdapter adapter; 
    ArrayList<ItemData> search = new ArrayList<ItemData>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        ActionBar.LayoutParams lp = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.actionbarlayout, null); // layout which contains your button.
        actionBar.setCustomView(customNav, lp);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
        listView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getApplication(), search,listView, title);      
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**ListViewAdapter**

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemData> { 
protected ListView mListView;  
private final List<ItemData> items;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
TextView title;
private static int checkBoxCounter = 0;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ItemData> items,ListView listview, TextView title) {
    super(context, resource, items);
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.items = items;
    this.title = title;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items != null ? items.size() : 0;
}

@Override
public ItemData getItem(int position) {
   return super.getItem(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        int layout = R.layout.item_layout;
        v = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
        holder.tt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.team);
        holder.tt12 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        holder.img1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.plus);
        holder.img2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.minus);

        holder.imag1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             checkBoxCounter ++;
        }
        });

        holder.imag2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             checkBoxCounter --;
        }
});
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    ItemData p = items.get(position); //getItem(position);
    holder.tt1.setText(p.getTitle());
    holder.tt12.setText(p.getDetails());
    holder.img.setImageDrawable(p.getImage());
    holder.img1.setImageDrawable(p.getImageplus());
    holder.img2.setImageDrawable(p.getImageminus());
    Log.i("fff", "getView: image = " + p.getImage());
    //load image directly
    return v;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tt1, tt12;
    ImageView img,img1,img2;   
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. The code you give me is already working for me but i need add function when i press plus image button the value should increase in action bar. thanks

Comment: check my answer again

Comment: thats fine i am able to solve the problem thanks again

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do it, but i recommend via interface:

You can implement an interface in your activity which will pass events from adapter to Activity for example:

```
public interface OnButtonClicked {
public void updateUI();
```

}

In your MainMenu activity implement this interface:

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity implements onButtonClicked
```

When creating your adapter pass the activity object to the adapter:

inside your adapter declare private variable:

```
onButtonClicked interface;
```

and in the adapter constructor initialize it:

```
ListViewAdapter(OnButtonClicked interface)
{
   this.interface = interface;
}
```

Lastly when detecting click event in the adapter update the parent activity ui using the onButtonClicked updateUI method (run on UI thread)

Recommend reading about interfaces.

Alternatively you can always try to cast the adapter context to the calling activity:

```
MainMenu activity = (MainMenu) context;
activity.updateUI();
```

Comment: Thanks for all of you. eventually i have solve my problem. by adding this line TextView textView = (TextView) customNav.findViewById(R.id.textView); thanks again